Do associated models where clauses act as an AND between the models?
I am trying to do a bit of a complicated query but wanted to simplify it here for help.
Basically, i have mixed data in table coming from different tables associated by one parent table. In here, i wish to allow the idea of putting in a search time and searching all these different models as such
await ModalA.findAll({
    where: whereClauseA,
    include: [
      {
        model: ModalB,
        where: whereClauseB
      },
      {
        model: ModalC,
        where: whereClauseC
      }
    ]
  });

Lets say a table in a web browser shows a row related to the ModelA data, and within that table u can click on a row and expand and show more data that belongs to ModelB/C. If the user wishes to search for some key word, visible to them in the browser, but behind the scenes it means searching for that in the rows for all three tables.
So something like this where main table has an and and others have an or
const whereClauseA = {
    [Op.and]: [
      {
        [Op.or]: [
          {someColumnName1InModelA: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}},
          {someColumnName2InModelA: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}},
          {someColumnName3InModelA: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}},
          // ... can add more columns to search 
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'SOME ID HERE'
      }
    ]
  };

  const whereClauseB = {
    [Op.or]: [
      {someColumnName1InModelB: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}},
      // ... can add more columns to search 
    ]
  };

  const whereClauseC = {
      someColumnName1InModelB: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}
  };

Now the problem i am seeing is, for model b and c, it seems to be ANDing them not ORing, so it appears (and note, im still learning sql and sequelize), it appears it looks for a result from all 3 tables or none at all. so I wish to return data from all 3 if the where matches, despite the results of the other tables. So something like this...
if search query in modela or in modelb or in modelc, return result
but what appears to be happening is,
if search query in modela and in modelb and in modelc, return result
Is there anything i can do about this?

Let's see the generated SQL.

You need to combine all conditions (from all 3 models) with OR on the main where using extended syntax for indicating included model columns tin the form $ModelName.ColumnName$ like this:
const whereClauseA = {
    [Op.and]: [
      {
        [Op.or]: [
          {someColumnName1InModelA: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}},
          {someColumnName2InModelA: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}},
          {someColumnName3InModelA: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}},
          // ... can add more columns to search 
          { '$ModelB.someColumnName1InModelB$': {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}},
          { '$ModelC.someColumnName1InModelC$: {[Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`}}
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'SOME ID HERE'
      }
    ]
  };

and remove the conditions from include options
